# Malformed mach-o image __TEXT segment maps start of file but is writable

Tags: macos, vst, mach

I'm having an issue loading a VST plugin in a VST host plugin that I'm writing. I've been successful loading most plugins that I've found but there seems to be one that is giving me weird issues. I can load it in adobe audition and in hosts that use the JUCE framework.

When dlopen is called I get this error, and I couldn't seem to find anything similar on the internet:

dlopen(/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST/Plugin Alliance/SPL De-Verb.vst/Contents/MacOS/SPL De-Verb, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find: Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST/Plugin Alliance/SPL De-Verb.vst/Contents/MacOS/SPL De-Verb: malformed mach-o image: __TEXT segment maps start of file but is writable

Running file on it shows me that it is a universal binary with two architectures:

$ file ./SPL\ De-Verb

```
SPL De-Verb: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [i386: Mach-O bundle i386] [x86_64]
SPL De-Verb (for architecture i386):    Mach-O bundle i386
SPL De-Verb (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
```

Here is the site for the plugin:
https://www.plugin-alliance.com/en/products/spl_de-verb.html

Here is the code I'm using to load it:

```
AEffect* newEffect = NULL;

// Create a path to the bundle
CFStringRef pluginPathStringRef = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL,
        pluginPath.c_str(), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
CFURLRef bundleUrl = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath
        (kCFAllocatorDefault, pluginPathStringRef,
        kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, true);

if (bundleUrl == NULL)
{
    blog(LOG_WARNING, "Couldn't make URL reference for VST plug-in");
    return NULL;
}

// Open the bundle
bundle = CFBundleCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, bundleUrl);
if (bundle == NULL)
{
    blog(LOG_WARNING, "Couldn't create VST bundle reference.");
    CFRelease(pluginPathStringRef);
    CFRelease(bundleUrl);
    return NULL;
}

vstPluginMain mainEntryPoint = NULL;
mainEntryPoint = (vstPluginMain) CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName
        (bundle, CFSTR("VSTPluginMain"));

// VST plugins previous to the 2.4 SDK used main_macho for the
// entry point name.
if (mainEntryPoint == NULL)
{
    mainEntryPoint = (vstPluginMain)
            CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName(bundle,
            CFSTR("main_macho"));
}

if (mainEntryPoint == NULL)
{
    blog(LOG_WARNING, "Couldn't get a pointer to plug-in's main()");
    CFBundleUnloadExecutable(bundle);
    CFRelease(bundle);
    return NULL;
}

newEffect = mainEntryPoint(hostCallback_static);
if (newEffect == NULL)
{
    blog(LOG_WARNING, "VST Plug-in's main() returns null.");
    CFBundleUnloadExecutable(bundle);
    CFRelease(bundle);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Maybe try thinning the binary out and see if the result is any different.

Comment: Still has the exact same error after running lipo on it to only have the x86_64 code

Comment: Sometimes the malformed type errors happens when an executable is packed, although that seems unlikely since you were able to thin it and it loads fine in the other hosts. Maybe post the code you're using to load the VST...

Comment: Just added the code that I have